# Capture job id of a job submitted by qsub

Tags: bash, qsub

I have been looking for a simple way to capture the job ID of a job submitted by qsub. I saw a suggestion was given by providing a name to the job, and using that name. But that's an indirect method. I tried this way but getting an error

```
jobID="qsub job.sh"
35546.cell0  (This is the output I want to capture)

$jobID

qsub -W depend=afterok:$jobID analyze.sh
```

Can anyone please suggest a neat way to capture the job ID from qsub?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is the output from `qsub job.sh`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try

```
qsub -W depend=afterok:$(qsub job.sh) analyze.sh
```

Comment: Could you explain what is going on here? Wouldn't the $(qsub job.sh) resubmit a job to the scheduler?